# ¿Como rotar la imagen de un jLabel?

Tags: java, jframe

```
 private void jButton1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
// TODO add your handling code here:
        int x, y;
        x = jLabel1.getX();
        y = jLabel1.getY();
        System.out.println(jLabel1.getLocation());//mostramos la posicion de la imagen

        switch (evt.getExtendedKeyCode()) {// captura las teclas
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                jLabel1.setLocation(x, y - 10);//arriba
                //Girar Hacia Arriba Imagen
                break; 
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                jLabel1.setLocation(x, y + 6);//abajo
                //Girar Hacia abajo Imagen
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                jLabel1.setLocation(x - 10, y);// derecha
                //Girar Hacia derecha Imagen
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                jLabel1.setLocation(x + 10, y); //izquierda
                //Girar Hacia izquierda Imagen
                break; // hace que la imagen se mueva con las teclas.
        }

        jLabel1.repaint();

    }
```

Como puedo hacer rotar una imagen que esta dentro de un jLabel dependiendo de la tecla que pulse

Comment: Mira [este artículo](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/), creo que te podría servir y es bastante sencillo.

Comment: lo voy a mirrar

Comment: hay que añadir algun import? porque no me va

Comment: Nop, abajo donde pone [Get the code](http://www.camick.com/java/source/RotatedIcon.java) te da el código fuente de la clase

Comment: lo e estado mirando y comprobando pero no me sirvió se puede hacer alguna otra manera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí tienes el ejemplo funcionando:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class RotateIcons extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RotateIcons w = new RotateIcons();
        w.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel basePanel;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JLabel label3;

    public RotateIcons(){
        setSize(600, 300);
        setTitle("Rotando iconos");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        basePanel = new JPanel();
        basePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        add(basePanel);

        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("android.jpg"));
        //Icono normal
        label1 = new JLabel(imageIcon);
        //Icono rotado 90 grados (down = rota hacia la derecha, up = rota hacia la izquierda)
        label2 = new JLabel(new RotatedIcon(imageIcon, RotatedIcon.Rotate.DOWN));
        //Icono rotado 45 grados
        label3 = new JLabel(new RotatedIcon(imageIcon, 45));
        basePanel.add(label1);
        basePanel.add(label2);
        basePanel.add(label3);
        pack();
    }

}
```

Clase RotatedIcon:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.Icon;

/**
 *  The RotatedIcon allows you to change the orientation of an Icon by
 *  rotating the Icon before it is painted. This class supports the following
 *  orientations:
 *
 * <ul>
 * <li>DOWN - rotated 90 degrees
 * <li>UP (default) - rotated -90 degrees
 * <li>UPSIDE_DOWN - rotated 180 degrees
 * <li>ABOUT_CENTER - the icon is rotated by the specified degrees about its center.
 * </ul>
 */
public class RotatedIcon implements Icon
{
    public enum Rotate
    {
        DOWN,
        UP,
        UPSIDE_DOWN,
        ABOUT_CENTER;
    }

    private Icon icon;

    private Rotate rotate;

    private double degrees;
    private boolean circularIcon;

    /**
     *  Convenience constructor to create a RotatedIcon that is rotated DOWN.
     *
     *  @param icon  the Icon to rotate
     */
    public RotatedIcon(Icon icon)
    {
        this(icon, Rotate.UP);
    }

    /**
     *  Create a RotatedIcon
     *
     *  @param icon the Icon to rotate
     *  @param rotate  the direction of rotation
     */
    public RotatedIcon(Icon icon, Rotate rotate)
    {
        this.icon = icon;
        this.rotate = rotate;
    }

    /**
     *  Create a RotatedIcon. The icon will rotate about its center. This
     *  constructor will automatically set the Rotate enum to ABOUT_CENTER.
     *
     *  @param icon the Icon to rotate
     *  @param degrees   the degrees of rotation
     */
    public RotatedIcon(Icon icon, double degrees)
    {
        this(icon, degrees, false);
    }

    /**
     *  Create a RotatedIcon. The icon will rotate about its center. This
     *  constructor will automatically set the Rotate enum to ABOUT_CENTER.
     *
     *  @param icon the Icon to rotate
     *  @param degrees   the degrees of rotation
     *  @param circularIcon treat the icon as circular so its size doesn't change
     */
    public RotatedIcon(Icon icon, double degrees, boolean circularIcon)
    {
        this(icon, Rotate.ABOUT_CENTER);
        setDegrees( degrees );
        setCircularIcon( circularIcon );
    }

    /**
     *  Gets the Icon to be rotated
     *
     *  @return the Icon to be rotated
     */
    public Icon getIcon()
    {
        return icon;
    }

    /**
     *  Gets the Rotate enum which indicates the direction of rotation
     *
     *  @return the Rotate enum
     */
    public Rotate getRotate()
    {
        return rotate;
    }

    /**
     *  Gets the degrees of rotation. Only used for Rotate.ABOUT_CENTER.
     *
     *  @return the degrees of rotation
     */
    public double getDegrees()
    {
        return degrees;
    }

    /**
     *  Set the degrees of rotation. Only used for Rotate.ABOUT_CENTER.
     *  This method only sets the degress of rotation, it will not cause
     *  the Icon to be repainted. You must invoke repaint() on any
     *  component using this icon for it to be repainted.
     *
     *  @param degrees the degrees of rotation
     */
    public void setDegrees(double degrees)
    {
        this.degrees = degrees;
    }

    /**
     *  Is the image circular or rectangular? Only used for Rotate.ABOUT_CENTER.
     *  When true, the icon width/height will not change as the Icon is rotated.
     *
     *  @return true for a circular Icon, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isCircularIcon()
    {
        return circularIcon;
    }

    /**
     *  Set the Icon as circular or rectangular. Only used for Rotate.ABOUT_CENTER.
     *  When true, the icon width/height will not change as the Icon is rotated.
     *
     *  @param circularIcon true for a circular Icon, false otherwise
     */
    public void setCircularIcon(boolean circularIcon)
    {
        this.circularIcon = circularIcon;
    }

//
//  Implement the Icon Interface
//

    /**
     *  Gets the width of this icon.
     *
     *  @return the width of the icon in pixels.
     */
    @Override
    public int getIconWidth()
    {
        if (rotate == Rotate.ABOUT_CENTER)
        {
            if (circularIcon)
                return icon.getIconWidth();
            else
            {
                double radians = Math.toRadians( degrees );
                double sin = Math.abs( Math.sin( radians ) );
                double cos = Math.abs( Math.cos( radians ) );
                int width = (int)Math.floor(icon.getIconWidth() * cos + icon.getIconHeight() * sin);
                return width;
            }
        }
        else if (rotate == Rotate.UPSIDE_DOWN)
            return icon.getIconWidth();
        else
            return icon.getIconHeight();
    }

    /**
     *  Gets the height of this icon.
     *
     *  @return the height of the icon in pixels.
     */
    @Override
    public int getIconHeight()
    {
        if (rotate == Rotate.ABOUT_CENTER)
        {
            if (circularIcon)
                return icon.getIconHeight();
            else
            {
                double radians = Math.toRadians( degrees );
                double sin = Math.abs( Math.sin( radians ) );
                double cos = Math.abs( Math.cos( radians ) );
                int height = (int)Math.floor(icon.getIconHeight() * cos + icon.getIconWidth() * sin);
                return height;
            }
        }
        else if (rotate == Rotate.UPSIDE_DOWN)
            return icon.getIconHeight();
        else
            return icon.getIconWidth();
    }

    /**
     *  Paint the icons of this compound icon at the specified location
     *
     *  @param c The component on which the icon is painted
     *  @param g the graphics context
     *  @param x the X coordinate of the icon's top-left corner
     *  @param y the Y coordinate of the icon's top-left corner
     */
    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();

        int cWidth = icon.getIconWidth() / 2;
        int cHeight = icon.getIconHeight() / 2;
        int xAdjustment = (icon.getIconWidth() % 2) == 0 ? 0 : -1;
        int yAdjustment = (icon.getIconHeight() % 2) == 0 ? 0 : -1;

        if (rotate == Rotate.DOWN)
        {
            g2.translate(x + cHeight, y + cWidth);
            g2.rotate( Math.toRadians( 90 ) );
            icon.paintIcon(c, g2,  -cWidth, yAdjustment - cHeight);
        }
        else if (rotate == Rotate.UP)
        {
            g2.translate(x + cHeight, y + cWidth);
            g2.rotate( Math.toRadians( -90 ) );
            icon.paintIcon(c, g2,  xAdjustment - cWidth, -cHeight);
        }
        else if (rotate == Rotate.UPSIDE_DOWN)
        {
            g2.translate(x + cWidth, y + cHeight);
            g2.rotate( Math.toRadians( 180 ) );
            icon.paintIcon(c, g2, xAdjustment - cWidth, yAdjustment - cHeight);
        }
        else if (rotate == Rotate.ABOUT_CENTER)
        {
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setClip(x, y, getIconWidth(), getIconHeight());
            g2.translate((getIconWidth() - icon.getIconWidth()) / 2, (getIconHeight() - icon.getIconHeight()) / 2);
            g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), x + cWidth, y + cHeight);
            icon.paintIcon(c, g2, x, y);
        }

        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

Para modificar el icono simplemente usa el método `setIcon` de JLabel:

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new RotatedIcon(imageIcon, 45)); //Pone un icono rotado 45 grados
```

Tan solo necesitas tener una referencia al `ImageIcon` que usaste para crear los jLabel en principio para poder rotarlo con `new RotatedIcon(ImageIcon, angulo)`

Resultado:

[image: Diferentes labels girados]

Comment: a mi la imagen me funciona pero el problema esta en como hago para colocarlo en la parte de `private void jButton1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)` porque el coche se mueve pero la imagen no se gira

Comment: Prueba con `jLabel1.setIcon()` pasándole un nuevo `RotatedIcon` con la referencia del `ImageIcon` que usaste para crear el `JLabel` en un principio y los grados de rotación que quieras

Comment: vale lo voy a mirrar

Comment: me funciono voy a ajustar los grados´

Comment: No hay método `initComponents()`. Ese método lo crea NetBeans cuando añades un nuevo formulario o GUI o cómo les llame. Este código está escrito por mí a mano y si te fijas, no hay método ninguno que se llame así en él.

Comment: si la me fije pero sin el `initComponents()` a mi no me funciona

Comment: Por eso lo que puse es un ejemplo. Yo no tengo acceso a todo tu código así que no puedo darte algo que funcione directamente con copiar y pegar. Te he dado un ejemplo totalmente funcional, ahora te toca a tí adaptarlo a tu proyecto :)

Comment: ya lo adapte pero como pusiste lo de la imagen entonces pense que era por el `initComponents()` y el programa funciona perfectamente

Comment: Ah no, lo de la imagen es que me está fallando IMGURL directamente al intentar subir la imagen al post, perdona.

Comment: a eso explica todo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112466/discussion-between-javier-g-raya-and-benito-b).